# Can't edit NewForm WebPart

Tags: ribbon

I added WebPart with list to my main view, so I want to edit NewForm of that List.

To do that I clic into list and go to NewForm:

[image]

Once I do it ribbon dissapear and it only appears if I clic into text area:

[image]

But is not the ribborn I want, I want ribbon to add WebPart like this:

[image]

Someone know why I don't have desire rebborn? Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will display put the page into Edit mode and allow you to add/remove web parts:

1. Navigate to the NewForm page.
2. Click the Settings gear (top right).
3. Click "Edit Page" on the Settings menu.

For some reason, in O365, Microsoft hides the ribbon on certain pages. This will display the ribbon on a page where it is hidden:

1. Click the Settings gear (top right).
2. Click "Show Ribbon" on the Settings menu.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have 1 day triyng to solve it, and is so simple, I just press "Edit Page", thank you so much!